# Filter List of Objects by list of strings in Angular Pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, pipe

I need to filter a list of Objects with a "chip-search" - so a list of words.
The filtering should work by an AND connection.

Assuming to have a list of Objects like:

```js
[
  {
    name: 'apple',
    color: 'red'
  },
  {
    name: 'apple',
    color: 'pink'
  },
  {
    name: 'berry',
    color: 'red'
  }
]
```

and we filter by this array

`['apple']`

there should be two results

when filtering with an array of two words:

`['apple', 'red']`

there should be only one result.

My approach is as following but doesn't work like expected:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'wordsFilter' })
export class WordsFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], words: string[]): any[] {
        if (!words || !words.length) return items;
        return items.filter(item => {
            let itemValues = Object.values(item);
            for (const val of itemValues) {
                if (words.every(word => (`${val}`).toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase()))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
}

//usage:
<li *ngFor="let item of items | wordsFilter: words">{{item}}</li>
```

Comment: Note that use a pipe to filter it's a pour performance. It's better to have two variables:`words` and `wordsFilter` and iterate over the second one

Answer (score 0):

You have your filtering wrong : You are checking that every `word` is present in **each** value. `'apple'` & `'red'` are never in the same value.

Here is a cleaned-up code:

```
const transform = (items: any[], words: string[]): any[] => {
  if (!words || !words.length) return items;
  const lowerWords = words.map(w => w.toLowerCase())

  return items.filter(item => {
    let itemValues = Object.values(item);
    return itemValues.every(val =>  lowerWords.includes(val.toLowerCase()))
  });
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA2gKBjA3tnGMAQwFsBTALhgHJiAHeucmgGgJ1DhACdqae5ACY0CAX3Y58hImSq0GTFpMJde-egjABrUTgkFphEhX4Ajcjx4BPNhxhq%20tQSPGYAupkyhIsKD2JIADNeUlQYAAoEKHJSCGpA63R3VhgAd14heJhoHi0Ac2SASgSwJPdUAD48AgQgyIBCDJ4smAAfNpgmzIgAOmYwfKgACyKYQSgAVx4wGGjYiABuAh9kbjTLAHUe8Oas3tIGCLSq9N6oEAAZEA2eAGFiCHIIoqKvHAnp2fm43qCEOAxHhRGJhFDVIw4ZiwH4ANWIcEm5Ag4QA8mYAFbkYBQXoANwRSIgINiRWWMk%20MzmoPhiORvXIeMs1giBLgp3gNy2PV6WmAiKEyNZCPOVy590ez1eb30ZMwYi8qxAzH6IHyEX8gQgIR4pAiiGgqXQdEYzDYzmENHcryAA)